# How would I put an end to unexpected output in the terminal window header?

Tags: macos, terminal

When I run a script in a terminal window there is a flickerfest of commands being run.
[image]
While this novelty item is cute for a day or two (or a year or two) it grows old on ya, eventually.
How would I stop that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try unchecking "Active process name" in Terminal preferences. See the image below which was taken from macOS Monterey version 12.5.

[image: window]

You may also wish to do this for tabs as well. See image below.

[image: tab]